Question regarding how to create a PDF/ Normal distribution from histogram
I have a theory question regarding Probability density functions, Histograms and Normal distributions and I just need someone to confirm whether my description (albeit basic) is correct or not.
I have attached an image of my question under this explanation if my written version looks confusing.
From what I know If I had a Histogram such that I had the frequency density on y axis, then in order to convert those y values into probability density,
I would do the frequency density/N( this is the same as writing frequency /N* class width) therefore, when we calculate the area of a bar we will get a probability value since it would be (frequency /N* class width)*class width, and class width cancel to leave frequency/N aka the probability.
We do this for every bar, and then we get 1 if we sum up those areas, a normal distribution is essentially the same idea but the class widths are approaching 0. It doesn't have to be a normal distribution per se but essentially just some curve with an area of 1 underneath.

But confusion arises when I have to take into account of the proportionality constant k since histograms are usually in the form of Area of bar = K * frequency, btw when I refer to the area of the bar here I'm referring to when the Y axis shows frequency density and not the pdf.
How would this whole process I described work then, do we just cancel out K in the process?
